# Track the devices in which email is opened

Tags: php, email, email-validation

I am tracking email open using custom PHP code.

I have placed a `<img src="wesbite.com/email-open/?EO=1&uID=13&nID=9a" >` which helps me in tracking the email open, I want to track the device in which the email has been opened for eg. Mobile, Desktop/Laptop, I tried using `HTTP_USER_AGENT` but it always gives one value "desktop". When I open this link `wesbite.com/email-open/?EO=1&uID=13&nID=9a` in my own browser from phone and PC it works fine.

I need a better way to track the device in which the email was opened.

Comment: http://mobiledetect.net/

Comment: and that's why I force my mail client to only show plain text mails

Comment: Most e-mail clients don't load pictures by default, so this will only work with users that read the email online or selects to load images for your email. Gmail opens images on the server to avoid tracking of the device, so even if you are able to get this to work it will only work for those that use an online reader that is not gmail. Is it really worth it to track what is left?

Comment: Our emails has relevant information in pictures, without that it is useless. Is there a way for HTTP_USER_AGENT to detect email opening devices? Is it possible with GA?